# IE Float Problem

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have a menu bar in which each button is an image floated to the right. It looks perfect in Safari, FF, and Chrome but in IE7 the buttons are grouped fine, but they appear about 50 pixels lower than the other browsers (out of the menu bar). Any tips on how to fix this? Thank you!

http://jsfiddle.net/mE2b8/

My CSS:

```
 #menu {
      width: 100%;
      height: 58px;
      background-color: #00653a;
    }

#menu_mid {
  width: 823px;
  height: 58px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  background-color: #00653a;
}

.menu_links {
  float: right;
  display: inline;
}
```

HTML:

```
  <div id="menu">
      <div id="menu_mid">
        <img src="assets/img/menu_rrt.gif" alt="RRT"/>
        <img src="assets/img/menu_contact.gif" alt="Contact" class="menu_links"/>
        <img src="assets/img/menu_news.gif" alt="Contact" class="menu_links"/>
        <img src="assets/img/menu_about.gif" alt="Contact" class="menu_links"/>
        <img src="assets/img/menu_home.gif" alt="Contact" class="menu_links"/>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Oops, I suppose that'd be helpful! IE7

Comment: There is something wrong with your CSS. Using float: right and display: inline makes completely no sense in my book. either delete display: inline or delete both (img by default are inline elements). More semantic way of your problem is to create a list : ul with id main menu_mid and each image inside li. According to image, always set height and width to safe time of browser to finding those values and to allow browser to reserve required space imidietely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be that the logo (or graphic with alt="RRT") does not have a width defined. I added an ID to the img element and then floated it left. Seems to be what you're looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/mE2b8/3/

Comment: float: right already sets display: block so you can delete this line

Comment: Thank you very much! Fixed it across multiple versions of IE.